# Fetch all the values ever passed to sink.add in Flutter stream

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart, flutter-streambuilder

Let's say that we want to create a stream which would contain a Map<String, String>. Now the catch here is that I want to create a function that would add new key-value pairs into this stream of Map<String, String>.

e.g.,

```
final _configMap = BehaviorSubject<Map<String, dynamic>>();
Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> get configMap => _configMap.stream;
Function(Map<String, dynamic>) get addConfigMap => _configMap.sink.add;
```

Now calling the sink addConfigMap will only accept a new map. **But my requirement here is to create a BehaviorSubject that would accept Key-Value pairs and whose stream will emit a Map containing all those key-value pairs that we have ever passed into it.** Is it possible ? If yes, then how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the "accumulator" map on the class, then map over the input elements of your stream, inserting the new elements into the stored `Map`, and finally emitting the stored `Map`:

```dart
class Foo {
  final _configMap = BehaviorSubject<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  Map<String, dynamic> _map = {}; // Store the map

  Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> get configMap => _configMap.stream.map((newMap) {
        _map.addAll(newMap);
        return _map;
      });

  Function(Map<String, dynamic>) get addConfigMap => _configMap.sink.add;
}
```

To use:

```dart
void main() async {
  final foo = Foo();

  foo.configMap.listen((map) {
    print(map);
  });

  foo.addConfigMap({"test-1": 1}); // Prints {"test-1": 1}
  foo.addConfigMap({"test-2": 2}); // Prints {"test-1": 1, "test-2": 2}
  foo.addConfigMap({"test-3": 3}); // Prints {"test-1": 1, "test-2": 2, "test-3": 3}
}
```